# Any one knows what the distribution with density $\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}$ is?

Tags: distributions, distribution-identification, rayleigh-distribution

As the title, any one knows what the distribution with density $f(x)=\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}$ is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution

Comment: I am not sure that the function $\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}$ (more correctly, $\frac{{x{e^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{{2t}}}}}}{{\sqrt {2\pi {t^3}} }}\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is even a valid density function. The function $\frac{xe^{ - \frac{x^2}{2t}}}{t}\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is the _Rayleigh_ density function (density of a $\chi_2$ random variable scaled by $t$), and so the function in question is not a density at all (except possibly when $2\pi t = 1$).

Comment: Over what values of $x$? For which values of $t$? If $x$ is intended to range over the positive real line and $t$ can take any positive value, it looks to me like that's only proportional to a density  (as Dilip has suggested already).

Answer (score 2):

You should be more careful, the function you have given takes negative values for $x<0$, so cannot be a density unless restricting the range of $x$. But assuming you meant the positive axes, what you have given is not a density, but a scaled version of the [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) with density
$$
   \frac{xe^{ - \frac{x^2}{2t}}}{t}\mathbf 1_{(0,\infty)}(x),
$$
assuming $t>0$.  See also the comments.